# SAP UI5 Route Pattern matched not triggered

Tags: sapui5

I am using master detail design. In the master details, Icontabfilter is placed to separate pending documents and processed documents. by selecting any one document either from pending records tab or processed records tab, Detail view will be displayed (for pending Approve button is enabled, for already processed Approve button is disabled).so, we have separate views for both Master and Detail pages. It is possible to have the document in both Pending and Processed tabs.[image: Layout]

Issue is when we have same document number in both pending and processed tabs as its has the same URL objectPatternMatched function is not getting triggered. Hence, the detail view is displaying incorrect data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the greedy property to true for the second route that should fire an event in your manifest file.

See the constructor for [sap.ui.core.routing.Route](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route%23constructor)

> Since 1.27. By default only the first route matching the hash, will fire events. If greedy is turned on for a route, its events will be fired even if another route has already matched.